# Matrix declaration in C

Tags: c, pointers

Is there any difference in:

```
char *foo[size];
```

and

```
char (*foo)[size];
```

In this example, the compiler complains if I declare my pointer with the first method:

```
void alloc_unitary_matrix(size_t size, char (*matrix)[size]) {
    matrix = malloc(size*size);
    memset(matrix, 1, size*size);
}

void main() {
   size_t size = 10;
   char (*matrix)[size];
   alloc_unitary_matrix(size,matrix);
}
```

What did I misunderstand?

Comment: Better declare as a `char **foo`. But you'll need to pass multiple size variables to functions.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a parsing issue rather than compilation, and if you remove `size` from the arguments declaration (which makes no sense anyway), using `char *matrix[]` or `char **matrix` is equivalent.